# How to prevent the perl compiler from changing the name of dynamic link library

Tags: raku, zef

I'm making a perl6 package which contains some c source files that will be compiled into a dynamic link library. I found that the name of the library, such as libperl.so,  will be changed into something like "A858A3D6EC5363B3D3F59B1.so" after "zef install". However, the name is used in python code as a module name(libperl). After the change, it is no longer a valid identifier. So, is it possible to prevent the change? If it is, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe one of https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl6%5D+zef+resources are helpful?

Comment: @raiph Thank you for the link!!! I should have considered to create a soft link.

Comment: This is probably something that should be reported and dealt with specially. Zef does that with every module, but I guess some like these should bet special treatment, even if it's only printing the way to create that symbolic link as advised

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if it's possible to do that. Maybe it is.
Inspired by @raiph's link, however, I decided to create a soft link. Now the package works well.